# How can I receive DbgPrint messages in windbg on windows 10

Tags: debugging, windbg, kernel-mode, windows-10

I have been googling and I feel this answer should be a simple one. I think that the keywords are however, too generic and are bringing up a lot of things related but not what I am looking for.

I am kernel debugging in Windbg connected to a VM in VMware. I am loading a driver and I noticed that I cannot view DbgPrint messages.

So far from Googling, I can see that I should have a value in this registry to change

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CCS\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter

I don't see however, a value for Debug Print.

I understand this was turned off for noise purposes. Is there a simple way to turn it on, even if temporary?

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to turn on the debug information is to modify the mask directly in WinDBG with this command :

```
kd> ed nt!Kd_Default_Mask 8
```

*The console will become massively verbose...*

Comment: Hi, perhaps do you know if there's any way to filter the logs for specific processes ? Thanks

Comment: @Zohar81 only turn it on when you hit a breakpoint and then turn it off at another breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

As per [Reading and Filtering Debugging Messages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/reading-and-filtering-debugging-messages):

> On the target computer, you can access the component filter mask in
>   the registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\Debug Print Filter. Using a registry editor, create or open
>   this key. Under this key, create a value with the name of the desired
>   component, in uppercase letters (for example, DEFAULT or IHVDRIVER).
>   Set this value equal to the DWORD value that you want to use as the
>   component filter mask (for example, 0x8 to display DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL
>   messages, in addition to DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, or set the mask to 0xF to
>   display all messages)